# How to keep same background in the whole application?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

How can I make my application have the same background everywhere? I've tried to do it with editing the theme but the problem there was that my app uses an animation in which, when you go to an new layout it slides over. So want I want is a way to have the same background everywhere and when a new layout slides in only textviews and buttons and sh*t should move. The background has to stand still at the same position.

Also, what is the best size for an background within an app? 1080x1920 is a bit slow :P

THANKS!!

What i've tried: (values/styles.xml)

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/background</item>
</style>
```

(androidmanifest)

```
    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen" >
    // unimportant things here
    </application>
```

Comment: <item name="android:background">@drawable/background</item>
to
    <item name="android: windowBackground">@drawable/background</item>

Comment: Thank! it works, but how about the size of the image i should use? it is really slow at the moment

Comment: Its slow because you are using xml and scaling, you can use a lower resolution or put it in the -nodpi folder and scale it only once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just set the background you need in the config file. Once you've done that, simple make sure you don't set the background anywhere else and you should be okay.